# How to create a multi-checkbox widget, where labels consist of multiple values that should be placed in individual HTML elements?

Tags: templates, cakephp, checkbox, widget, cakephp-3.0

**TODO**

- Checkbox list with key - value pairs.
- Key = id.
- Value (label) = three values combined. Only used for displaying data to the user.

**What I have now:**

```
$a->formatResults(function($results) {
    return $results->combine(
        'id',
        function($row) {
            return ' | ' . $row['_matchingData']['A']->name . ' |' . $row['_matchingData']['B']->name . '| . $row['C'] . '"';
        }
    );
});
```

**What I tried:**

```
$a->formatResults(function($results) {
    return $results->combine(
        'id',
        function($row) {
            return '
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="large-4 columns">
                        ' . $row['_matchingData']['A']->name . '
                    </div>
                    <div class="large-4 columns">
                        ' . $row['_matchingData']['B']->name . '
                    </div>
                    <div class="large-4 columns">
                        ' . $row['C'] . '
                    </div>
                </div>
            ';
        }
    );
});
```

**Current template (.ctp)**

```
echo $this->Form->input('a._ids', [
    'options' => $a,
    'multiple' => 'checkbox',
    'label' => false,
    'templates' => [
        'inputContainer' => '<div id="scroll_a" class="scrollable_input">{{content}}</div>'
    ]
]);
```

**What happens now**

The html is printed as 'plain' text.

What I actually like to have is that each checkbox is placed in a `<div class="row>` and that the checkbox is placed in a `<div class="large-3 columns">` and every other three values too.

**Edit**

Something like this

**Final html**

```
<div id="scroll_a" class="scrollable_input">
<div class="checkbox">

    <div class="row">
        <label for="users-ids-221">
            <div class="large-3 columns">
                <input id="users-ids-221" type="checkbox" value="221" name="users[_ids][]">
            </div>
            <div class="large-3 columns">
                ' . $row['_matchingData']['A']->name . '
            </div>
            <div class="large-3 columns">
                ' . $row['_matchingData']['B']->name . '
            </div>
            <div class="large-3 columns">
                ' . $row['C'] . '
            </div>
        </label>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: It would be good if you'd also add an example of what exactly you'd like the final HTML to look like!

Comment: Added, under 'Edit'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be possible by using the **[complex value syntax](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-select-pickers)** for the options, and custom templates with **[template variables](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#adding-additional-template-variables-to-templates)** for the individual label components.

You'd need to modify the `checkboxWrapper` and the `nestingLabel` template, the former to add the row wrapper, and the latter to add the columns, something along the lines of

```
'checkboxWrapper' => '<div class="checkbox"><div class="row">{{label}}</div></div>',
'nestingLabel' =>
    '{{hidden}}<label{{attrs}}>' .
        '<div class="large-3 columns">{{input}}</div>' .
        '<div class="large-3 columns">{{text1}}</div>' .
        '<div class="large-3 columns">{{text2}}</div>' .
        '<div class="large-3 columns">{{text3}}</div>' .
    '</label>',
```

Now the label widget can be fed with the custom template vars `text1`, `text2` and `text3`. In order to achieve this, the options that you are passing to the form helper would need to be structured like this

```
[
    [
        // the `text` and `value` keys are required in order for the widget to properly
        // recognize this syntax, the `text` key will not be used in the custom template
        // but it must still exist and is not allowed to be `null`, so just fill it with
        // something else
        'text' => false,
        'value' => 1,
        'templateVars' => [
            'text1' => 'text 1',
            'text2' => 'text 2',
            'text3' => 'text 3'
        ]
    ],
    [
        'text' => false,
        'value' => 2,
        'templateVars' => [
            // ...
        ]
    ],
    // ...
]
```

where `value` would be the rows id, and `text 1`, `text 2` and `text 3` would be your other row values.

Since this is purely for presentation purposes and highly form helper specific, you should probably build the options in the view layer, for example directly in the template, and from your controller just pass the non-formatted query (`$a`) to the view, something like

```
$options = $a->map(function ($row) {
    return [
        'text' => false,
        'value' => $row['id'],
        'templateVars' => [
            // template variables are not going to be escaped, so don't forget to
            // apply it on your own when necessary
            'text1' => h($row['_matchingData']['A']->name),
            'text2' => h($row['_matchingData']['B']->name),
            'text3' => h($row['C']),
        ]
    ];
});

echo $this->Form->input('a._ids', [
    'options' => $options,
    'multiple' => 'checkbox',
    'label' => false,
    'templates' => [
        'checkboxWrapper' => /* ... */,
        'nestingLabel' => /* ... */,
        'inputContainer' => /* ... */,
    ]
]);
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Form > Creating Select Pickers](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-select-pickers)**
- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Form > Adding Additional Template Variables to Templates](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#adding-additional-template-variables-to-templates)**
- **[Cookbook > Collections > Iterating > Cake\Collection\Collection::map()](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/collections.html#Cake%5CCollection%5CCollection::map)**
- **[API > \Cake\View\Widget\MultiCheckboxWidget::render()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.View.Widget.MultiCheckboxWidget.html#_render)**

Comment: Great! Exactly what I was looking for! Just succesfully implemented this in my application. I also think sending a raw query to the view is in this case the best option. The only thing I don't exactly understand is how the templateVars in the $options variable are linked with the 'templates' in the form input.